# E/dalvikvm(786): Could not find class 'org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem' in android activity

Tags: java, android

```
Below is the Code :
//imports
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;


        try{
            // Creating Input Stream 
            InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(filename);
            POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

            // Create a workbook using the File System 
            HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

            // Get the first sheet from workbook 
            HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
```

//can u please help me out what is wrong with it . I have included the respective jars in //the libraries of java Build path of eclipse .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this all of the code? Where's the class declaration?

Comment: no this is not the full code , just pasted the relevent code snippet that is causing the exception .

Answer (score 0):

Order and Export the included jars in Java Build Path.

Comment: Everything is done .. order and export , there are no compile time errors. All the jars are available in the build path of that project in eclisep